# two divs in the same row after and before ZOOM IN

Tags: css

I have two divs here: http://jsfiddle.net/TXSfN/
CSS CODES:

```
#div1{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50%
}
#div2{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%
    display: inline-block;
    height: 263px;
    float: right;
}
```

I'm trying to set the two divs in the same line also after zoom-in/zoom-out in browser(CTRL +/CTRL -).
The problem isn't with setting the two divs in the same line, it's with the zoom-in/out, when I zoom-in/out the div with the long content get's longer and longer with the height and the one with the short content stay as it is.
Is there a way to set the two divs in the same row for every action(zoom-in/out).

Comment: Have you tried this? `#div1{float: left;) #div2{float: right;} #div1, #div2{display: inline-block;}` This might be helpfull.

Comment: You need to set the content height too. Set its height to a fixed pecentage. And add `overflow: scroll` This will help you.

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I don't understand "fixed pecentage", also the first solution and `overflow: scroll` didn't work :/

Comment: You don't understand fully. First you need to give them a display inline to make it sure that they are facing each other. Then give both a percentage height, I mean this one `height: 60%;`; as in your example. Then try using `overflow: scroll;`. Thats how you can control the overflow of text. Else you might consider deleting the text. As the div is gonna carry whole the text you cannot prevent that!

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan I would like the same solution without scrollbar :/

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TXSfN/2/

Set a max-height to the 2 divs, and overflow-y: auto the first div to keep the height the same and not have the content force it to become larger.

**CSS**

```
#div1{
    background-color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    max-height: 250px;
    width: 50%
}

#div2{
    background-color: blue;
    width: 20%
    display: inline-block;
    height: 250px;
    max-height: 250px;
    float: right;
}
```

Comment: can't that be done without the `overflow: scroll`(The scrollbar)?

Comment: Well, as you will see if you remove the overflow-y: scroll, the box will stay the same height because of the constraints, but your content will flow outside of it. If this OK with you, then you can remove the scroll. Otherwise, the content inside either has to bleed outside of it, or be hidden by overflow.

Comment: If you don't want the scrollbar you can put a container around div1. Put overflow hidden on the container div and extend div1 past the width of the parent container (to hide the scrollbar). Updated sketch fork here: http://jsfiddle.net/wVpwp/1/